# Add space between string to display in HTML file

Tags: java

I am doing an assignment that create a HTML from java code. Does anybody knows how to add a space between words? For example, when I type

> java fun

then create the HTML it just display the word without a space

> javafun

I did try to add a space like `textRow.append("<td>" + words.get(i).getWord().replaceAll("", " ") + "</td>");` 
it didn't work

This is my code:

```
private void addWordlist(ArrayList<WordTracker> words) {
    // Holds one line of table text at a time.
    out.write("<table align='center' >");
    StringBuilder textRow = new StringBuilder();
    int rowcounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        if (rowcounter == 0) {
            textRow.append("<tr class='answerkey'>");
        }
        textRow.append("<td>" + words.get(i).getWord() + "</td>");
        rowcounter++;
        if (rowcounter == 5 || i == words.size() - 1) {
            rowcounter = 0;
            textRow.append("</tr>");
        }
    }
    out.write(textRow.toString());
    // add closing remarks
    out.write("</table>");
    out.write("</br>");
}

public class WordTracker{
    private String word;
    private int size;
    private Coordinate beginCoordinate;
    private Coordinate endCoordinate;


    public WordTracker(String word_in, int size_in, Coordinate beginCoord_in, Coordinate endCoord_in) {
        size = size_in;
        word = word_in;
        beginCoordinate = beginCoord_in;
        endCoordinate = endCoord_in;
    }

    public String getWord(){
        return word;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }

    public Coordinate getBeginCoordinate(){
        return beginCoordinate;
    }

    public Coordinate getEndCoordinate(){
        return endCoordinate;
    }

    public void setWord(String word_in) {
        word = word_in;
    }

    public void setSize(int size_in) {
        size = size_in;
    }

    public void setBeginCoordinate(Coordinate beginCoordinate_in) {
        beginCoordinate = beginCoordinate_in;
    }

    public void setEndCoordinate(Coordinate endCoordinate_in) {
        endCoordinate = endCoordinate_in;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the string representation of PlacedWordTracker.
     * Prints the word, its number and its coordinates.
    */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return word + ", size:" + size + ", begin:" + beginCoordinate + ", end:" + endCoordinate + "\n";
    }
}
```

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Try using `&nbsp;` instead of a space.

Comment: @LeejaySchmidt thank you,i tried that but still doesn't work, it gave space for each character like j a v a f u n

Comment: @LeejaySchmidt I don't think so, it is the same in the `ArrayList`

Comment: How about `textRow.append("<td>" + words.get(i).getWord() + "&nbsp;</td>");`? Does this fix it by any chance? The `replaceAll` won't work. What you got for that was expected behaviour.

Comment: When i try to use `replaceAll("&nsbp;", " ")` didn't give a space. Either `textRow.append("<td>" + words.get(i).getWord() + "&nbsp;</td>");` still doesn't give a space as well

Comment: How exactly does your `WordTracker` look like? You need to either preserve the whitespace or "java" and "fun" as two separate words when reading them in. If there is a space between them, that space will be printed. You cannot just replace `""` afterwards.

Comment: I definitely need to see how you are reading in words to `WordTracker` and how `getWord` works for `WordTracker` as well. It appears to be an issue there, not with how the HTML is being generated.

Comment: I've added `wordTracker` class

Comment: And how do you read words?